# find duplicated groups in dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as described below and I need to find out the duplicate groups based on the columns - value1,value2 & value3 (groups should be grouped by id).
 I need to fill column 'duplicated' with true
if the group appears elsewhere in the table,if group is unique fill with false.

note: each group has different id.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
                   'value1': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3'],
                   'value2': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3'],
                   'value3': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3'],
                   'duplicated' : [] 
                   })
```

[image]

expected result is:

[image]

I tried this, but if is comparing rows, I need to compare groups (grouped by id)

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/path/Desktop/example.xlsx')

# False : Mark all duplicates as True.
data['duplicates'] = data.duplicated(subset= ["value1","value2","value3"], keep=False)

data.to_excel('C:/Users/path/Desktop/example_result.xlsx',index=False)
```

and I got:

[image]

note: the order of the records in the both groups doesnt matter

Comment: Does the order maters? for example, if in the group C, the lines with the 1 and the 2 are exchanged position, would it still be "duplicates"?

Comment: @Ben.T order of rows in group doesnt matter

Comment: @ncica that makes it a bit more complicated.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter, sorry it was my mistake , the code was correct nut I didnt notice that I write that part of code inside of a wrong function, tnx for hint :)

Comment: @ncica: you're welcome, but in the future, please notify us. We're volunteers that help. Note that if you did in fact comment back and then deleted the question, I'm not going to be able to see it given my low reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

First `sort_values` just in case, `set_index` the id and `stack` to change the shape of your data and get a single column with to_frame

```
df_ = (df.sort_values(by=["value1","value2","value3"])
         .set_index('id')[["value1","value2","value3"]]
         .stack()
         .to_frame()
      )
```

Second, you can append an `set_index` with a `cumcount` per id, drop the level of index with the name of the original column (Value1 ...), `unstack` to get one row per id, `fillna` with a random value and use `duplicated`.

```
s_dup = df_.set_index([df_.groupby('id').cumcount()], append=True)\
           .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)[0]\
           .unstack()\
           .fillna(0)\
           .duplicated(keep=False)
print (s_dup)
id
A     True
B    False
C     True
D    False
dtype: bool
```

Now you can just `map` to the original dataframe:

```
df['dup'] = df['id'].map(s_dup)
print (df)
   id value1 value2 value3    dup
0   A      1      1      1   True
1   A      2      2      2   True
2   A      3      3      3   True
3   A      4      4      4   True
4   B      1      1      1  False
5   B      2      2      2  False
6   C      2      2      2   True
7   C      1      1      1   True
8   C      3      3      3   True
9   C      4      4      4   True
10  D      1      1      1  False
11  D      2      2      2  False
12  D      3      3      3  False
```

Comment: Is there a way to set multiple labels, like "1", "2", "3", to distinguish the different duplicated groups?

Answer (score 2):

This may not be very efficient but it works if duplicated groups have the same "order".

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
                   'value1': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3'],
                   'value2': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3'],
                   'value3': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3'],
                   'duplicated': [False] * 13
                   })


def check_dup(df, col1, col2):
    # Checks if two groups are duplicates.
    # First checks the sizes, if they are equal then checks actual values.

    df1 = df[df['id'] == col1][['value1', 'value2', 'value3']]
    df2 = df[df['id'] == col2][['value1', 'value2', 'value3']]
    if df1.size != df2.size:
        return False
    return (df1.values == df2.values).all()


id_unique = set(df['id'].values)  # set of unique ids
id_dic = dict.fromkeys(id_unique, False)  # dict for "duplicated" value for each id
for id1 in id_unique:
    for id2 in id_unique - {id1}:
        if check_dup(df, id1, id2):
            id_dic[id1] = True
            break

# Update 'duplicated' column on df
for id_ in id_dic:
    df.loc[df['id'] == id_, 'duplicated'] = id_dic[id_]

print(df)
```

```
   id value1 value2 value3  duplicated
0   A      1      1      1        True
1   A      2      2      2        True
2   A      3      3      3        True
3   A      4      4      4        True
4   B      1      1      1       False
5   B      2      2      2       False
6   C      1      1      1        True
7   C      2      2      2        True
8   C      3      3      3        True
9   C      4      4      4        True
10  D      1      1      1       False
11  D      2      2      2       False
12  D      3      3      3       False
```