# How to label duplicated groups in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Based on this problem: [find duplicated groups in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61934808/find-duplicated-groups-in-dataframe/61935846#comment123242897_61935846) and this dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
                   'value1': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3'],
                   'value2': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3'],
                   'value3': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3'],
                   })
```

How can i mark in this dataframe in the additional column duplicated the different duplicate groups (in the value columns) by unique label, like "1" for one duplicated group, "2" for the next and so on? I found examples here on slack to identify them as false and true, but one only with "ngroup", but did not work.

My real example has 20+ columns and also NaNs in between. I have created the wide format by pivot_table from original long format, since i thought getting duplicated entries is the better from wide. Duplicates should be found in N-1 columns, which names I summarize by using subset on a list comprehension excluding this identifier column

That is what i had so far:

```
df = df_long.pivot_table(index="Y",columns="Z",values="value").reset_index()
subset = [c for c in df.columns if not c=="id"]
df = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=subset,keep=False)].copy()
```

We use pandas 0.22, if that does matter.

The problem is, that when I use

```
for i, group in df.groupby(subset):
    print(group)
```

I basically don't get back any group.

Comment: `df['duplicated']= df.groupby(['value1','value2','value3']).ngroup()`

Comment: Of course you will need to remove `duplicated` from your dataframe constructor, as you can't have an empty list as the column values.

Comment: I tried that already on my real dataset, but got only the same label "-1" in all rows. However, since i aleady created the df with duplicated (keep=False), I expected to get different labels.

Comment: I removed the "duplicated" in the example above, since I don't have it in my real dataframe, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby_ngroup` as suggested by @Chris:

```
df['duplicated'] = df.groupby(df.filter(like='value').columns.tolist()).ngroup()
print(df)

# Output:
   id value1 value2 value3  duplicated
0   A      1      1      1           0  # Group 0 (all 1)
1   A      2      2      2           1
2   A      3      3      3           2
3   A      4      4      4           3
4   B      1      1      1           0  # Group 0 (all 1)
5   B      2      2      2           1
6   C      1      1      1           0  # Group 0 (all 1)
7   C      2      2      2           1
8   C      3      3      3           2
9   C      4      4      4           3
10  D      1      1      1           0  # Group 0 (all 1)
11  D      2      2      2           1
12  D      3      3      3           2
```

Comment: If this fails can you share a real sample of your data?

Comment: This is how I would like to get the result. But yes, this fails, i get only "-1". It's confidential, so hard to get you real code. Let me see.

Comment: I don't understand why you get -1 with `ngroup`. Maybe, try to scramble your data?

Comment: `-1` appears for ngroup if the group identifier is `NaN` or `NaN`-like. @Corralien `pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.nan, 1, 1, 2, 2]}).groupby('A').ngroup()`  -> `[-1  0  0  1  1]`

Comment: OK, is there a way to get ngroup working, or another method besides ngroup?

Comment: @Rockbar. Yes, you can replace NaN by a value. For example: `df.fillna(np.inf).groupby(df.filter(like='value').columns.tolist()).ngroup()`

Answer (score 0):

Ok the last comment above was the correct hint: The NaNs in my real data are the problems, which also groupby does not allow for identifying groups. By using fillna() before using groupby, the groups can be identified and ngroup does add me the group numbers.

```
df['duplicated'] = df.fillna(-1).groupby(df.filter(like='value').columns.tolist()).ngroup()
```